# Max limit on min magnitude of vector

Tags: discrete-mathematics, vectors, asymptotics, linear-programming

If there exist two sets $X_1$ and $X_2$ of vectors $\bar{x}\in\mathbb{Z}^d$ where each vector has a magnitude $|\bar{x}|\leq M$, and there exists a non-empty set $A=\{\bar{a}\in\mathbb{Z}^d\ |\ \bar{a}\cdot\bar{x}>0\ \forall\ \bar{x}\in X_1,\ \bar{a}\cdot\bar{x}<0\ \forall\ \bar{x}\in X_2\}$, can we say anything about the maximum possible value of $\min_A |\bar{a}|$ (i.e., the smallest magnitude of any vector in $A$; I don't know if the notation I used for the min value is correct) as a function of $M$ and $d$?

Big-$O$ notation for $\min_A |\bar{a}|$ is sufficient. We also know that $x_1=1\ \forall\ \bar{x}\in X_1\cup X_2$, where $x_1$ is the first component in $\bar{x}$, if that changes anything.